# Any performance benefits of using apc_store vs apc_add (or vice versa)?

Tags: php, caching, store, addition, apc

While I understand the differences between apc_store and apc_add, I was wondering if using one or the other has any performance benefits?

One would think apc_store COULD be a bit quicker since it does not need to do a check-if-exists before doing the insert.

Am I correct in my thinking?

Or would using apc_add in situations where we know FOR SURE that the entry does not exist prove to be a bit faster?

Answer (score 0):

Short: `apc_store()` should be slightly slower than `apc_add()`.

Longer: the only difference between the two is the `exclusive` flag passed to [`apc_store_helper()`](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/blob/61639af67447244746bc4bacd9619d67c6fe9ee8/php_apc.c#L603) that in turns leads to the behavior difference in [`apc_cache_insert()`](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/blob/244473d2bca7aff7ce24a58651ab8a261669d99d/apc_cache.c#L761).

Here is what happens there:

```
if (((*slot)->key.h == key.h) && (!memcmp((*slot)->key.str, key.str, key.len))) {
    if(exclusive) {
        if (!(*slot)->value->ttl || (time_t) ((*slot)->ctime + (*slot)->value->ttl) >= t) {
            goto nothing;
        }
    }
    // THIS IS THE MAIN DIFFERENCE
    apc_cache_remove_slot(cache, slot TSRMLS_CC);**
    break;
} else 
    if((cache->ttl && (time_t)(*slot)->atime < (t - (time_t)cache->ttl)) || 
        ((*slot)->value->ttl && (time_t) ((*slot)->ctime + (*slot)->value->ttl) < t)) {
        apc_cache_remove_slot(cache, slot TSRMLS_CC);
        continue;
    }

    slot = &(*slot)->next;      
}

if ((*slot = make_slot(cache, &key, value, *slot, t TSRMLS_CC)) != NULL) {
    value->mem_size = ctxt->pool->size;

    cache->header->mem_size += ctxt->pool->size;
    cache->header->nentries++;
    cache->header->ninserts++;
} else {
    goto nothing;
}
```

The main difference is that `apc_add()` saves one slot removal if the value is already present. Real world benchmarks would obviously make a lot of sense to confirm that analysis.